# Server Cannot find NATS from inside Docker Container

Tags: docker, go, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

For a project I have a Go Server running in a Docker container, a NATs Server, and a standalone client.
The server tries to send messages through NATs. To connect to NATs, it uses the following code:

```
var nc, err = nats.Connect(nats.DefaultURL)
    
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer nc.Close()
```

But when I try to run the server, I get an error which causes the program and container to stop: `panic: nats: no servers available for connection`. This seems to mean that the program Server in the container cannot find the NATs that is running.
Both Windows-server and NATs are running in the same Docker Network.
And when I enter into the Container and use telnet to access Nats at the port nats:4222, telnet finds the NATs server correctly

```
/app # busybox-extras telnet nats:4222
Connected to nats:4222
INFO {"server_id":"NBFTCFLMIEXINXIRG5LSJ2MGT4J574OYHHJ7AANWDTWQERKZ76LG7RVQ","server_name":"NBFTCFLMIEXINXIRG5LSJ2MGT4J574OYHHJ7AANWDTWQERKZ76LG7RVQ","version":"2.9.6","proto":1,"git_commit":"289a9e1","go":"go1.19.3","host":"0.0.0.0","port":4222,"headers":true,"max_payload":1048576,"client_id":12,"client_ip":"172.20.0.3","cluster":"my_cluster"}
```

I have already tried to change the URL that `nats.Connect` is connecting to, and none of them have worked. I have tried `"nats"` and `"nats:4222"` and `"nats://nats:4222"`, and the  NATs URLs as well. I do not know what I am doing incorrectly.

The Dockerfile of the Container looks like this:

```
FROM golang:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apk update
RUN apk add  ffmpeg libsm libxext
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o server
EXPOSE 50051
CMD ["./server"]
```

I set up NATs with the command `docker run -d --rm --name nats  --network=mybridge -p 4222:4222 nats`, the server with `docker run -d --name windows-server  --network=mybridge  -p 50051:50051 windows-server`
The Server works correctly when it is running outside of a container. How do I make the program access NATs from within a container?

Comment: Can you please try `mybridge`'s ip address on your system (you can find it with `ip a s` in linux) and port 4222? Also, I think it would be better to create docker-compose for this.

Comment: My problem is twofold: first, I am trying to do this part on a Windows Machine. Second, after docker container working, I am going to be using the image in kubernetes.

Comment: In the kubernetes part I think you shouldn't have any issue because your networking there is based on services. On the windows machine I think you can get the ip address with `ipconfig`.

Comment: It ends up working when I shift from a Windows-based Machine to a Linux based one